# Group favorite tag with remove tag button

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-watching

Strictly a visual issue, but would it be possible to group the favorite tags with their associated remove button so that they appear on the same line? It's a little strange to see a remove tag button at the beginning of a line with its tag all the way at the end of the previous line.